# Joining Video files and adding chapters for each

Tags: video, video-editing

There have been a few similar posts asking my question in the past but either the apps are only 32-bit or the apps do not exist for download now. Any application suggestions that could preferably merge multiple mp4 video files and add chapters for each video clip would be helpful.

Comment: ffmpeg is both 64bit and still current.  Based on your question, this linked question does what you're looking for.

Comment: @Allan I’m not very well versed with ffmeg is there an application that can do this without needing terminal?

Comment: I just did a quick search and ran across this utility:  [FilmoraPro](https://bit.ly/2CNntl5) and if you want free and open source there's [OpenShot Video Editor](https://www.openshot.org/) both work on 64bit windows and are current.  Perhaps you could add an answer?